# How do I exclude a folder when performing file operations i.e. cp, mv, rm and chown etc. in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, filesystems

How do you exclude a folder when performing file operations i.e. cp etc.

I would currently use the wild card * to apply file operation to all, but I need to exclude one single folder.

The command I'm actually wanting to use is `chown` to change the owner of all the files in a directory but I need to exclude one sub directory.

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065447/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-when-performing-file-operations-i-e-cp-mv-rm-and-cho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Inverse Globbing:**
You want an *inverse match* of a glob, I would do it like the following:

You can do an inverse match with a newer bash if you enable extended globbing.  For example, to match everything that doesn't have foo or bar in the name:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !(*foo*|*bar*)
```

Or just everything that doesn't have foo:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !(*foo*)
```

**Find:**
You could also use find (this is the most robust option I think), and use ! to negate a match, and then run the command with `xargs -0`:

```
find . ! -iname 'foo' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

**Simple:**
Just mv the folder somewhere else, do what you need to do, and put it back :-)

Answer (score 1):

rsync -arv --exclude={files} {Destination}

Answer (score -1):

the find solution spawns one chown process per file, sometimes that can be a problem. This solution spawns only one perl process:

```
find . | perl -nle "chown($(id -u user), $(id -g group), \$_) unless m/foo/"
```

Comment: No, the `find` solution doesn't do this if you use it with `xargs`. Your script would also not only exclude the directory `/foo`, but also the file `/bar/foo` and the directory `/foobar`.

Comment: Yes, you have to adjust the regular expression as needed. Might I also point out that glob based solutions will also have the problem of matching /foobar